# What is the dividing line between a low-rep user and a high-rep user in negating/not negating upvotes when his account is closed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, votes

A high-rep user recently closed his account, with no effect on my rep. (I am sorry to see him go.)  I know that he gave me at least several upvotes and at least one acceptance.   When low-rep users close their accounts, the upvotes they awarded are negated.  I've seen a few small drops in my rep because of this.

What is the dividing line between a low-rep user and a high-rep user in negating/not negating upvotes when his account is closed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Stack Exchange employees have deliberately avoided specifying the exact numbers, I guess to avoid encouraging voting-fraudsters to try to hit them or maybe just to give SE more freedom to adjust them as necessary without people getting confused: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/306255)

Comment: @sumelic that's a good answer. My thoughts exactly.

Comment: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/306255) is exactly the answer. Unfortunately we can't mark cross-site duplicates.